# How to cancel a DS-160 form

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I filled and submitted a DS-160 form in early december but did not take an appointment from the embassy after that , a few facts have changed since I filled that form , my sister became a citizen whom I mentioned as PLR and my travel history has changed (I am visiting canada in the meanwhile) , so my question is should I be filling a new DS-160 form or my old form still valid ?if its not do I need to cancel it ?

Comment: I think the title of the question isn't right since you're asking if you need to re-submit the form?

Comment: Are you intending to proceed with the application that the DS160 was for, but haven't done it yet? Or are you not going to do the visit the DS160 was for?

Comment: @DJClayworth Thanks for you comment, which is quite correct. I have deleted my Answer.